# Can't open rptproj file in VS 15 Preview 4

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I have downloaded BIDS and SSDT for 2015, but these don't seem to allow me to open a .rptproj file in my sln. It tells me that the application is not installed. How can I open this? It opens perfectly fine on vs 2012.

Comment: Do you mean VS 15 Preview 4 or VS2015? These are 2 separate things - installing SSDT for VS2015 from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx will install on top of Visual Studio 2015 (or if none exists, it installs the Integrated Shell). However VS 15 Preview 4 is the next version of Visual Studio and since the BI projects rely on some things not available yet (for example SSIS requires VSTA) and so support is not yet available in that product.

Comment: I did mean VS 15 Preview 4. I installed VS 2015 beside VS 15 and installed the SSRS package stuff. I wish there was a solution for VS 15! :) If you post this as an answer, I'll give you a nice little check mark! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the SQL BI project types (SSAS, SSRS, SSIS) are not supported on Visual Studio "15" Preview releases. The BI projects rely on some things not available yet (for example SSIS requires VSTA) and so support is not yet available in that product. The list of available versions to install is on the [SSDT download page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx) and will be updated when future versions are supported.

For now, Visual Studio 2015 is the recommended version to use - it is backwards compatible for all project types through SQL Server 2012-2016, with relational DB projects, SSAS and SSRS supported back through SQL Server 2008.